# decodeURIComponent in Erlang

Tags: javascript, unicode, erlang, yaws

I encode my data on client side with encodeURIComponent.

```
encodeURIComponent($('#...').val()),
```

How to decode it on the yaws server?

Comment: google's first search response is your answer to your question https://gist.github.com/816291

Comment: @Kishore, still hope what there ready solution in Erlang libraries((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something in the [http-uri module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/http_uri.html#decode-1) of the inets application which might help